# CSS Formatting Issue

Tags: css

I have been creating a mobile site based on oding from iWebKit 5, I have been using their css stylesheet and all is working fine, however the formatting of the css is all on one line, this obviously makes it confusing and almost impossible to read, so I wish to format it. I have tried many online formatters but they somehow either compress the code and screw it up or they rearrange it and it doesn't end up working. I have also had issues with certain formatters removing what they deem "bad attributes" which are actually iDevice specific styles.

So my question is, is there something/someone that could help me re arrange my code into a readable but obviously functioning css stylesheet?

Here is the link to the stylesheet:

http://pastebin.com/czuuaPyn

Comment: Have you tried [ProCSSor](http://procssor.com/)? Your link won't load, either. Please put your CSS on Pastebin, or another more reliable server.

Comment: Your link doesn't load for me, can you post it over at pastebin.com?

Comment: It does load, it's just really slow. Probably because none of us are anywhere near Australia :-)

Comment: This should probably be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://pastebin.com/czuuaPyn is the link to the CSS, I shall try ProCSSor and report back :)

Comment: ProCSSor works a treat for me.

Comment: Just loaded it, took a couple of minutes to come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hardly ever have to do this the other way around but when the occasion does arise, I go for an online-tool such as http://cssbeautify.com/. It's pretty good for "untangling" css.

Comment: CSS Beautify did it perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

- Open the file in any editor that has Search+Replace
- Replace `{` with `{\n\t`
- Replace `;` with `;\n\t`
- Replace `}` with `\n}\n`
- Tidy up any irregularities (particularly comments, possibly media queries)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

http://pastebin.com/CmXhA87P

Ran it through a [Codebeautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/) without any filters or modifiers enabled.